# microsoft Jscript runtime error in ie9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, runtime-error, visual-web-developer-2010

I have developed one web application using Visual Web Developer 2010 express, MVC 2 model.  It is a simple application sending and retrieving data of 5 fields.

When it is running in Chrome everything works fine, but in IE 9 I get a dialog box with `microsoft Jscript runtime error` including "Break", "Continue" and "Ignore" buttons.

It is really surprising to me as the same works fine in Chrome.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've had an error like this after a installed a smiley toolbar plugin for IE. On debugging I saw the error was coming from a styleTag.innerHTML object. Microsoft has a guide on using innerHTML. You can check it out here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx